# Oracle SQL Update column with data from another table using three conditional statements

Tags: sql, oracle

Scenario:

I have two separate tables (table 1 and table 2)
I want to update a column from table one with the value of a column from table 2

Case 1:

I need columns b,c and d in table 1 to match b,c and d in table 2 before the update occurs

Case 2:

Column b in table 1 has a true value but Column b in table two references a look up (example in table 1 column b may have a value of blue but in table 2 column b has the value 14567 which is the id in a lookup table that references blue)

How would you accomplish getting this update completed?

Comment: Clear as mud. Trying to rephrase what I understood: Both tables have columns a, b, c, d, of comparable data types between the two tables. You must update t1.a using the value in t2.a, where (t1.b, t1.c, t1.d) matches (t2.b, t2.c, t2.d). This is complicated further because the values in t2 must be replaced with lookup values found elsewhere. OK. Questions: (1) is this "lookup" business true for column t2.b only, or also for t2.c and t2.d? (2) For each (b, c, d) in t1, will there always be **at most** one match in t2?

Comment: Obviously, if there can be more than one match, then the whole "update" thing is nonsensical. **Which** of the matching rows from t2 should be used to update t1?

Comment: Hello Mathguy let me expound; you are correct in general.  only T2.columnB has an associated lookup the other combinations have like values just stored in different tables.  Hope that makes it clearer.  If not let me know.  thanks for sharing your brain bud.

Answer (score 0):

create table ta as
select 1 ID,'Alex' Name , 27 age from dual
union
select 2 ID,'Bob' Name , 32 age from dual;

create table tb as
select 1 ID,'Alex' Name , 29 age from dual
union
select 5 ID,'Dick' Name , 24 age from dual;

update ta a
set a.age =  (select b.age from tb b  where a.id=b.id and b.name=a.name)
where exists ( select 1 from tb where a.id=tb.id and a.name = tb.name);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table `lookup` has columns `b` (corresponding to `t2.b`) and `col_x` (corresponding to `t1.b`), you could do something like this, using the `merge` statement:

```
merge into t1
  using (
          select t2.a, l.col_x, t2.c, t2.d
          from   t2 join lookup l on t2.b = l.b
        ) s
    on (t1.b = s.col_x and t1.c = t2.c and t1.d = t2.d)
when matched then update
set  t1.a = s.a
;
```